# The id-selector does not work within php

Tags: javascript, php, html

my javascript won't respond to my id-tag within php code:

```
    else {
                    echo '<form = "nav-login" method="post" onsubmit="return noEmptyUserFields();" action="includes/login.inc.php">
                        <input type="text" id="uidz" name="uid" placeholder="Username/e-mail">
                        <input type="password" id="pwdz" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
                    </form>
                    <a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>';
                }
```

But it responds to my javascript which is outside of the php which looks like this:

```
        <form class="signup-form" method="post" onsubmit="return noEmptyUserFields();" action="includes/signup.inc.php">
        <input type="text" id="first" name="first" placeholder="Firstname">
        <input type="text" id="last" name="last" placeholder="Lastname" >
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" >
        <input type="text" id="uid" name="uid" placeholder="Username" >
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" ></p2>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button></form>
```

How come it won't respond to the id-selector within php?

I have included  `<script src="includes/javascript.js"></script>`
on both.

My javascript looks like this (noEmptyLoginFields) :

```
    if (email.trim().length < 1)
    {
        alert('Email must be filled out');
        return false;
    }
    else if(pwd.trim().length < 6)
    {
      alert('Password must contain atleast 6 characters');
      return false;
    }
    else if (first.trim().length < 1)
    {
        alert('First name must be filled out');
        return false;
    }
    else if (last.trim().length < 1)
    {
        alert('Last name must be filled out');
        return false;
    }
    else if (uid.trim().length < 1)
    {
        alert('Username must be filled out');
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}


 function noEmptyLoginFields()

     var uidz = document.getElementById('uidz').value;
      var pwdz = document.getElementById('pwdz').value;

      if (uidz.trim().length < 1)
        {
            alert('Username and password must be filled out!');
            return false;
        }
        else if(pwdz.trim().length < 1)
        {
          alert('Username and password must be filled out!');
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `<form = "nav-login"` something's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the same function name for both form validations, which is causing the error. I advise you to handle form validation purely in javascript using event handlers:

```
document.querySelector("#formId").addEventListener("submit", function() {
  // if(...) return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry that's a mistake form mine, it is different in the code. I think it might have to do that I need to declare the id:s within the php right? Something like this? document.getElementById('uidz').value;